Use ADB from Android to control another Android device
i want develop an app for Android to control another Android device with ADB because I need all its features.
All the Android devices have the developer options active and are in the same Wi-Fi but i need to enable the tcpip with the usb connection and i want to enable it by connecting USB to another Android device and not a PC with Windows, MacOS or Linux.
I saw that it's possible to use ADB from another Android with the Wireless Debug option but not all devices have that, because of this i want to use the usb connection and launch the command  adb tcpip {port} and after connect to the device with adb connect {ip}:{port}.
I also want that this app recognize USB connections automatically and run in the background (with a service maybe?).
Is this possible?
I expect that the Android app recognize the other Android devices connected with USB and launch ADB commands to them.

I think you can refer to this project https://github.com/updeshxp/scrcpy-android
